# GDB how to set break point in linked files?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

So lets say I have my main file: main.c, linked with file1.c and file2.c where file1 and file2 include their header files: file1.h, file2.h

I compiled them together like so:

```
gcc main.c file1.c file2.c
```

which creates the `./a.out` executable to be run.

In GDB how do I set a break point in my main.c? I've tried

```
b main.c
```

which gave me this output:

```
Make break-point pending on future shared library load? yes or no
```

to which I responded `yes` but it never sets a break-point anywhere even after I say `b 232` : the line number, I even tried `b main 232` and `b main.c 232` but non of these work either..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the following (see [GDB doc](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_28.html)):

```
break main.c:232
```

And don't forget to compile with `-g`, otherwise line number information will not be present in the generated program.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to @MarcoBonelli's answer you can use

```
break main.c:main
```

or since there cannot be more than one `main` function in a project you can simply use

```
break main
```

this has the advantage of not having to search for the line number.